# How can I get the name of each tag in tag-it by jquery?

Tags: jquery, tags, tag-it

Currently I am using tag-it to my work. I have create tagbox & i can write on tag by using : https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it. But I need to know the value of each tag in that tagbox. How can I get this ? Please suggest me.

Html code :

```
<ul id="myTags" ></ul>
<input type="hidden" id="tag" style="width:400px;height:40px;" value=""  placeholder="Add tags" />
```

Jquery code :

```
$("#myTags").tagit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [assignedTags](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#assignedtags) method

```
var tags = $("#myTags").tagit("assignedTags");
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/592za/2/) for an example.

Comment: As I am new in query, can you give an example to show that tags in console ? when I wrote that line my browser shows:Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tagit prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'assignedTags'

Comment: first you need to initialize the plugin by calling `$("#myTags").tagit();` - in dom ready... then when you need you can call `$("#myTags").tagit("assignedTags");`

Comment: Actually I dont understand, first you need to initialize the plugin by calling $("#myTags").tagit(); - in dom ready

Comment: Can you help me for rate plugin in jquery? Please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521438/how-to-show-ratting-form-database-value-for-every-post-in-a-blog-site